# Storing the last iteration in a loop(python)

Tags: python, loops, poisson

So I have 2 variables mean and service consisting of the following values:

```
mean=[5.76,6.5,7,5,4.5,6,9,2.5,3,5.5]
limit=[90,80,95,96,98,85,82,75,90,91]
```

Now,I have applied `poisson` function on the variable mean:

```
from scipy.stats import poisson
for m in mean:
    r_v=poisson(m)
    r_v1.append(r_v)
```

Next what I need to do is obtain the sum of pmfs of all the values of mean(with the number of occurrences starting from 0) and compare those to the corresponding values in limit. I need to obtain the number of occurrence for which the sum of pmfs is greater than or equal to the corresponding value in limit. For example, for mean =5.76, (pmf(0)+pmf(1)...+pmf(9))*100=93.2, which exceeds 90 in the limit variable for 9 occurences.
I've run the following code which seems to work fine:

```
for r,s in zip(r_v1, limit):
        l=[]
        z=0
        while True:
            y=r.pmf(z)
            l.append(y)
            z+=1
            if round(sum(l),2)*100>=s:
                break
Store=%z
```

The issue is, when I'm trying to store the last occurrence of z at which `round(sum(l),2)*100>=s`, I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR:root:Line magic function `%z` not found.
```

Can somebody please help me rectify the error in the code? Thanks a lot.

Comment: why are you writing `Store=%z` instead of `Store=z`?

Comment: hi, Store=z is not giving me the number of occurrences. I had read somewhere that %helps you obtain the last iteration or something like that. I'm not exactly sure how to go about it.

Comment: where does `r_v1` get defined?

Comment: I haven't mentioned it in the question, r_v1=[]

Comment: ok and what do you expect the result to be for z here?

Comment: As I've mentioned in the example, I need to obtain z for which the sum of pmfs will be greater than or equal to the corresponding values under the column limit.

Comment: And is the result for your example 10? Because that's what I get, but I don't now how to verify.

Comment: 9 i guess, but I think you're on the right track. can you store it for all the 10 observations in an array?

Comment: youre're right it will be 10, since the iteration starts from 0. Can you store it for all the obs?

Comment: Did the answer fix your issue or is still anything unclear?

Comment: so for mean =5.76 you got 10 iterations right? I need the number of iterations for all the values of mean similarly, to be stored in some variable which I can print/display subsequently.

Comment: @Darkonaut, buddy any update?

Comment: Had to fight with SO's formatting. Does this look right?

Comment: You're welcome! Still don't quite understand what you're actually doing here so... ;)

Comment: its an operations research based case study actually. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%` is the prefix for invoking magic line functions within IPython's interactive shell and there is no `z` line magic function, hence you get this error.

type `%quickref` in IPython and you get an overview over the available magic functions or [readthedocs](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/tutorial.html#magic-functions).

---

Your problem was that you were trying too much in one step. Try getting the right result for one input and then accumulate in another step:

```
def calc(mean_, limit_):

    def inner(m, s):
        r = poisson(m)
        l = []
        z = 0
        while True:
            y = r.pmf(z)
            l.append(y)
            z += 1
            if round(sum(l), 2) * 100 >= s:
                return z, l

    return [inner(*args) for args in zip(mean_, limit_)]
```

Calling `calc(mean, limit)` gives:

```
[(10,
  [0.0031511115984444414,
   0.018150402807039979,
   0.052273160084275148,
   0.10036446736180832,
   0.14452483300100394,
   0.16649260761715656,
   0.15983290331247035,
   0.13151964615426115,
   0.094694145231068075,
   0.060604252947883679]),
 (10,
  [0.0015034391929775724,
   0.009772354754354215,
   0.031760152951651209,
   0.068813664728577653,
   0.11182220518393866,
   0.14536886673912017,
   0.1574829389673803,
   0.14623415761256733,
   0.11881525306021086,
   0.08581101609904139]),
 (12,
  [0.00091188196555451624,
   0.0063831737588816145,
   0.022341108156085643,
   0.052129252364199796,
   0.091226191637349643,
   0.1277166682922895,
   0.14900277967433773,
   0.14900277967433773,
   0.1303774322150455,
   0.10140466950059107,
   0.070983268650413558,
   0.045171170959354162]),
 (10,
  [0.006737946999085467,
   0.033689734995427337,
   0.084224337488568321,
   0.1403738958142805,
   0.17546736976785063,
   0.17546736976785068,
   0.1462228081398754,
   0.10444486295705395,
   0.065278039348158651,
   0.036265577415643714]),
 (10,
  [0.011108996538242306,
   0.049990484422090385,
   0.11247858994970336,
   0.168717884924555,
   0.18980762054012446,
   0.17082685848611215,
   0.1281201438645839,
   0.082362949627232548,
   0.046329159165318316,
   0.0231645795826592]),
 (9,
  [0.0024787521766663585,
   0.014872513059998144,
   0.044617539179994441,
   0.089235078359988937,
   0.13385261753998332,
   0.16062314104797995,
   0.16062314104798009,
   0.13767697804112569,
   0.10325773353084421]),
 (13,
  [0.00012340980408667956,
   0.0011106882367801166,
   0.0049980970655105232,
   0.014994291196531574,
   0.033737155192196056,
   0.06072687934595293,
   0.091090319018929264,
   0.1171161244529091,
   0.13175564000952278,
   0.13175564000952278,
   0.11858007600857066,
   0.097020062188830414,
   0.072765046641622894]),
 (4,
  [0.0820849986238988,
   0.20521249655974699,
   0.25651562069968376,
   0.21376301724973648]),
 (6,
  [0.049787068367863944,
   0.14936120510359185,
   0.22404180765538775,
   0.22404180765538775,
   0.16803135574154085,
   0.10081881344492458]),
 (10,
  [0.0040867714384640666,
   0.02247724291155237,
   0.06181241800676901,
   0.1133227663457432,
   0.15581880372539689,
   0.17140068409793663,
   0.15711729375644187,
   0.12344930223720431,
   0.084871395288077939,
   0.051865852676047694])]
```